# Wordpress htaccess causing redirect loop on root only without 'www.'

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, redirect-loop

I installed a WordPress app on an OpenShift machine and added CNAMES to it (on CloudFlare).

I started getting a redirect loop error only when I was going to the website without www. and only on root. Going to wp-admin, for example, with or without the www. worked well.

Then I commented my .htaccess and put a message on index.php. The message is shown, both with and without www.

I got the default .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Do you know what could be wrong with my settings?

@edit
www.porta8080.com.br

Comment: Hey Victor, what is your permalinks setting? If it isn't set to default what happens if you do set it.

Comment: @DominickDeChiera hey. It is set to Post name/name of post. changed now and the same happens

Comment: Ok. Are you using cloudflares ssl setting? There seems to be a lot of issues with that and Wordpress resulting in a redirect loop.

Comment: Also in the settings what is set for wordpress Address URL or Site Address URL settings? If the www. is included what happens if you set it to just `http://example.com`

Comment: First running your website without www. After that you added www to the site?

Comment: @DominickDeChiera haha never heard about that, but now the problem is when I use www. check it ou http://porta8080.com.br/

Comment: @KaushaMehta no. actually this is a new website. it doesnt even have content yet. when I was setting things up I tried the URL without www. and realised it was buggy :/

Comment: For me it works with www.porta8080.com.br when i write porta8080.com.br it is not running for me.

Comment: i was making some tests. but it still doesn't work